# macro - split text in a cell using token

Tags: excel, vba

I am having a cell with values

```
XX 99999 - X99, XX 99999 - X99, XX 99999 - X99
```

X - denote Alphabets
9 - denote Number

i have to read this cell and

- split it using "," to get array of `XX 99999 - X99`
- Spit it using " "  and "-"  there after to get array of `xx`, `99999`, and `X99`.

Can this be done **without using** "text to column", that is using some functions in excel?
Since i need to use the separated contents to filter some other data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the [Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x627e5f%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) function on MSDN. The below is split into two sections.

1. The below code firstly splits the string and assigns each comma seperated value to strSplit.
2. It then further splits the sub string by " " and assigns each piece to pieceSplit() which is then output into the immediate window.

The last part you can change and apply to your project.

```
Dim str As String, piece As Variant
Dim strSplit() As String, pieceSplit() As Variant
Dim i As Double, j As Double

str = "XX 99999 - X99, XX 99999 - X99, XX 99999 - X99"

strSplit = Split(str, ",")
ReDim pieceSplit(UBound(strSplit)) As Variant

For i = 0 To UBound(strSplit)

    pieceSplit(i) = Split(strSplit(i), " ")

Next

For Each piece In pieceSplit

    For j = 0 To UBound(piece, 1)

        Debug.Print piece(j)

    Next j

Next
```